# Custom Configuration Handler for multiple types?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a custom configuration handler for my library. That part is all working today and I'm able to read the custom config section properly.

Here's the problem. Today my XML node looks like:

```
<myNode value="test" />
```

Now I need some more flexibility, so I'm expanding the flexibility of my XML ala XAML:

I can have:

```
<myNode value="test" />
```

OR:

```
<myNode>
   <value>
      ...
   </value>
</myNode>
```

so value can either be an element or an attribute.

Currently my property looks like:

```
[ConfigurationProperty("value")]
public string Value
{
    get
    {
        return (string)this["value"];
    }
}
```

.NET doesn't allow me to have two "values", nor does it let me specify Value as an "object".

Is there a trick of some sort to allow for an element and attribute with the same name? Or do I pretty much need to completely re-write the deserialization? :(

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the XML library, but perhaps writing this: `public new string Value` will fix your issue?